# Magento 2.4.1 controller 404

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I have created a form when I submitting it going on 404 :
Form file

```
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
            <form id="vendor_register" method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= $block->getUrl('vendor/index/post'); ?>">
                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="firstname">First name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-validate='{"required":true}'>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="lastname">Last name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-validate='{"required":true}'>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="actions-toolbar float-right">
                            <div class="primary">
                                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="Create an Account">
                                    <span>Create an Account</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>                       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Works\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Post implements HttpPostActionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        die("works");
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code is right .

Your issue at `<?= $block->getUrl('vendor/register/post'); ?>`

Your action class name is `Test\Works\Controller\Index\Post` it means

```
<?= $block->getUrl('vendor/index/post'); ?>
```

**vendor** and should be  **route id** . See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#example-of-routing-usage

Comment: I have corrected it but now in controller post value is empty